# animated toggle button

Tags: android, toggle, android-animation

I have created animated toggle and it works perfect if `android:checked="true"` ie: it plays drawable from 1-9 but if `android:checked="false"` its stuck at drawable 10 but it should play from 10-20 .It works perfect from then on but when the app starts it has the above problem .

Why is it stuck at drawable 10 when in reality it should be at 20 as that is the final image.(Off) currently as its stuck at 10 it looks like its still ON .

///////////////////

**btn_toggle.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true"  android:drawable="@drawable/animatedbutton_on" />
            <item android:state_checked="false"  android:drawable="@drawable/animatedbutton_off" />
</selector>
```

//////////////////

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/ToggleButton01"
        android:layout_width="174dp"
        android:layout_height="235dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_toggle_bg"
      android:checked="false"
       />
```

//////////////////////////

btn_toggle_bg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+android:id/background" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
    <item android:id="@+android:id/toggle" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_toggle" />
</layer-list>

</LinearLayout>
```

//////////

animated_button_on.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:oneshot="true" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/1" android:duration="200" />
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/2" android:duration="200" />
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/3" android:duration="200" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/4" android:duration="200" />
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/5" android:duration="200" />
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/6" android:duration="200" />
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/7" android:duration="200" />
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/8" android:duration="200" />
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/9" android:duration="200" />
 </animation-list>
```

////////////////

animatedbutton_OFF.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:oneshot="true" >
      <item android:drawable="@drawable/a14" android:duration="200" />
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/a15" android:duration="200" />
         <item android:drawable="@drawable/a16" android:duration="200" />
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/a17" android:duration="200" />
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/a18" android:duration="200" />
         <item android:drawable="@drawable/a19" android:duration="200" />
         <item android:draw

able="@drawable/a20" android:duration="200" />
 </animation-list>
```

///////////////

CustomToggleButtonDemo.java

```
public class CustomToggleButtonDemo extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        ToggleButton tg=(ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.ToggleButton01);
        tg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                 if (isChecked) {
                        // The toggle is enabled
                     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "ON", 5).show();
                    } else {
                        // The toggle is disabled
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "off", 5).show();
                    }

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You must rename your file from "animatedbutton_OFF.xml" to "animatedbutton_off.xml".
And from "animated_button_on.xml" to "animatedbutton_on.xml"

Comment: Thank you for your reply .Why will renaming the xml work ? Please explain.

Comment: it's not just renaming it's renaming to lower case. It has restrictions like no numeric start, no capital letters and no hyphens etc.